# Program about Fibonacci numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am obliged to write program that will show minimal quantity of Fibonacci numbers which sum is equal to     `k`    number which user write into program.

So for example user writes `1070`
And the program will show `987 89 -5 -1` (because all of these numbers are Fibonacci numbers (you can add or substract to get desired sum).

I have problem to think about solution to this problem.

I wrote code to get all Fibonacci numbers from 0 to 46.

```
#include <iostream>
unsigned long long Fibbo[47];
void preapare()
{
        Fibbo[0] = 0;
        Fibbo[1] = 1;
        i = 2;
        while (i<47)
        {
              Fibbo[i] = Fibbo[i - 1] + Fibbo[i - 2];
              i++;
        }    
}
int main()
{
    preapare();
    int k=0;
    std::cin >> k;
}
```

I will be glad for any help. You can use Fibonacci Number as many times as you will. For example you can do 1+1+1+1+1

Comment: You have to make some effort. At least so that we can discern what level of expertise you have. It is also hard to see what the code in the question (broken as it is) has to do with the larger problem.

Comment: Think about what the previous indexes will be when `i` is less than two.

Comment: @David Hefferman  I build Fibbo table to store Fibonacci numbers. I thought about getting the the biggest possible Fibonacci number that is closest to it, and than trying to fill the gap between this number and k which is given by the user. My problem is this, that how can I determine whether my set of numbers is minimal or not? Should I try all possible combinations?

Comment: @BoBTFish You can use Fibonnaci Number as many times as you will. It does not have to be distinct. You can use 1 for example as many times as you can.

Comment: @MarcinMajewski Also, your array is uninitialized, so `Fibbo[i] += Fibbo[i - 1] + Fibbo[i - 2];` won't do any good. You want `=` instead of `+=`.

Comment: @MarcinMajewski Its a math concept, code is easy enough, algorithm not, see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void prepare( vector<int> & fibos ) {  ... }  // along the lines we see in OPs code

int findClosest( int n, vector<int> & fibos ){ // return Fibonacci number closest to n
  int fi = 0;
  for( std::vector<int>::iterator it = fibos.begin() ; it != fibos.end(); ++it){
    if( abs(*it - n) < abs(fi - n) ){
      fi = *it;
    }
  }
  return fi;
}

// The algorithm:
// lookup closest Fi, add "signed" to terms
// reduce n, adjust sign and call recursively 
void sum( int n, vector<int> & fibos, vector<int> & terms, int sign = 1 ){
  if( n == 0 ) return;
  int fi = findClosest( n, fibos );
  terms.push_back( sign*fi );
  sum( abs(n - fi), fibos, terms, n - fi > 0 ? sign : -sign );
}

int main() {
  vector<int> fibos;
  prepare( fibos );
  vector<int> terms;
  int n = 1070;
  sum( n, fibos, terms );
  cout << n << " =";
  for( std::vector<int>::iterator it = terms.begin() ; it != terms.end(); ++it){
    cout << " " << *it;
  }
  cout << endl; 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK, removed the wrapper function, sign has default.

Answer (score 1):

For user input:

Before the while loop, you need to get the input, save it to a variable, and use that in your while condition. Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
...
int k_val = 0;
std::cout << "Enter the value for k: ";
std::cin >> k_val;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `prepare()` fixed:

```
unsigned long long* preapare(const size_t n) {
        unsigned long long* Fibbo = new unsigned long long[n];
        Fibbo[0] = 0;
        Fibbo[1] = 1;
        for(size_t i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
              Fibbo[i] = Fibbo[i - 1] + Fibbo[i - 2];
        }
        return Fibbo;    
}
```

then you'll have to memory manage the returned array;

Comment: You should always say how it was broken and what you changed. But that's not what the question was asking about in any way. Also, I don't see adding the need for manual memory management as an improvement.

Comment: @Dukeling of course one would use a `std::vector` or `std::array`, cache for reuse, _etc_, _etc_.  But I didn't want to stray to far away from his original effort.  You are free to explain _why_ this code is better/worse than the original if you like.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this, the code will solve the grater fibonacci numbers to be add so the result will be the specified number:

fiboMax return a sequence with the fibonacci number less to the input number.
getiboSec return a sequence with the bigger fibonacci numbers that sum the input number.

```
'''
Created on 15/01/2014

'''
def fiboMax(num):
    ret = [0,1]
    a = 1
    b = 2
    while b < num:
        ret.append(b)
        tmp = a + b
        a = b
        b = tmp
    return ret

def getFiboSec(num):
    fiboSec = []
    fiboNumbers = fiboMax(num)
    i = len(fiboNumbers) - 1
    while num > 0 and i > 0:
        fiboNum = fiboNumbers[i] 
        while(fiboNum <= num):
            fiboSec.append(fiboNum)
            num -= fiboNum
        i -= 1
    return fiboSec


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = 20
    print(fiboMax(num))
    print(getFiboSec(num))
```

output:

```
figonnaci number to 20 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
fibonacci number that sum 20 = [13, 5, 2]
```

It doesnt work with negative numbers, anyway its solving the problem but not the efficient way.

Comment: This won't necessarily give the optimal result, consider that negative numbers are allowed - consider something like 232 - the optimal is `233 - 1`, but your solution will give a few more numbers.

Comment: @Dukeling, Thats true, then is pretty hard to get it, I dont know about that maths, Ill edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the indexes -2 and -1 in your loop. Your variable `i` should start at 2. You also try to add values to pointers. None of your values in `Fibbo[]` are set.

Comment: @de_dux This is not solving the algorithm, consider posting comments instead of fully answers