# Fibonacci series using arrays (as long as user input)

Tags: arrays, function, for-loop

I am currently a beginner in programming learning, my professor has instructed me to do a program with the instructions below. However when i wrote my program I did the following to take the input from the user on how long the array should be however because  my array size isnt defined it gives me an error but the professor hasnt instructed me to specify a size so im really confused :S

**My attempt :**

```
void displayarray(int n){

int i;
int aray[]={0,1};

for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("%i", aray[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

}

int main()
{ int n;

```
scanf("%i",&n);

displayarray(n);

getchar();
getchar();
```

}

**The Task assigned:**

> The Fibonacci numbers are a famous sequence of numbers. They begin with 0 and 1, and then the next value in the sequence is the sum of the previous two values.
>
> 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765
>   (fib[8] is 21 -- remember to start counting from 0!)
>
> Write a program that calculates the Fibonacci sequence.
>
> -Make a function that accepts n, which is the number of integers to generate.
>
> -Declare an array, initialize it with only the first two Fibonacci numbers, then calculate the rest.
>
> -Display the sequence for n=10 and n=20.
>
> -Try generating output for n=50. If anything goes wrong in this step, you don't need to fix it. Just add a comment explaining what happens, and why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Program about Fibonacci numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135996/program-about-fibonacci-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate all the Fibonacci sequence by only using a 3 lenght array. Initialize the first two elements of the array with the two first numbers of the Fibonacci sequence (0 and 1) and then, with these two values, calculate the third number of the sequence.

```
 int f[3];

 f[0] = 0;
 f[1] = 1;
 f[2] = f[0] + f[1]
```

Try to figure out what to do in the for loop to calculate the Fibonacci number for any integer n.

Comment: the thing is i dont want it to be a 3 digit sequence i want it to be as big as 'n' which would be scanned by the user

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you should do something like this:

you have f[0] and f[1], with this calculate f[2] and print the result, store the value in a variable or whatever.
Now you have the value of f[1] and f[2], so you can calculate the next number of the Fibonacci sequence and print the result again. Repeat the process as many time as necesary.

You'll have to iterate through the for loop n - 2 times (the -2 is because you already know the first two numbers of the sequence).

Answer (score 0):

You can use "malloc()" or "calloc()" function to allocate array of given size.

You need to declare it like

```
int *array;
array = malloc(n, sizeof(int));

// do something
free(array)
```